# Bug removing childs in Firebase android with CreatedTimeStamp (TimeServer)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to remove sent items to the Firebase Database
But I need to delete it in a certain time
The problem is this I am using the example of a firebase engineer
Using it on my phone works fine (Android 6.0)
But using it on a lollipop (Android 5.0) is deleted in a second, when in the code should delete in days

The variable "durationEentM" is a long like 1 or 2

```
if(durationEventM != null){
    long cutoff = new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(durationEventM, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    Query oldItems = FirebaseUtils.getPostMusicalRef().orderByChild("createdTimestamp").endAt(cutoff);
    oldItems.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getChildren() != null && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0){
                for (DataSnapshot itemSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    itemSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It seems *very* unlikely that `long cutoff = new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(durationEventM, TimeUnit.DAYS);` would give a different result on Lollipop. It's much more likely something else is going wrong. Did you step through the code and check if the values are what you expect them to be?

Comment: If the values are as expected, for example you can select 5 values
Between 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Those are the days of duration, in android 6.0 goes well but in android 5.0 it deletes the server in seconds @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem. Maybe it's due to a different in our devices. To rule out most of these, can you run just this code `System.out.println(new Date().getTime() - TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.DAYS));` and tell us what you get in logcat?

Comment: I use another method thanks! :D